# Python - Numerical integration using t as parameter and as variable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, integral

I am trying to implement a numerical integration. Specifically,

[image: Integral]

I am using the trapezoidal rule one gets the following analytical expression

[image: Analytical]

When I try to implement it numerically.

```
gamma=0.1 #parameter

Tmax=100 

N=100000 #number of steps

t=np.linspace(0,Tmax,N)

B=np.random.rand(len(t))

def A(t):
    A=np.zeros(len(t))
    trapezi=0
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        trapezi+=(np.exp(-gamma*(Tmax-t[i]))*B[i])
    h=Tmax/N
    A=h*(trapezi+1/2*(B[-1]+B[0]*np.exp(-gamma*Tmax)))
    return A
```

where I have created a random B matrix.

The problem is that right now the output A(t) is just an single value (i.e. for this t I get A(t)=0.47), but what I need is an array of the function going from t=0 to t=t. This is my main problem: **how to use the variable t as both a parameter in the integration and as a variable**.

Any advice would be highly welcomed.

Comment: The start is the solution formula for `A'+gamma*A=B, A(0)=0`. Just solve this IVP using the trapezoidal method to get an equivalent result, but with a full value table in one loop.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are right, it was much more easy to solve the differential equation than the integral equation. Thanks :)